# Is Hazelcast's built in CountAggregation really inefficient?

Tags: java, mapreduce, hazelcast

I've been looking into replacing our Oracle database of currently-executing commands with a Hazelcast distributed map implementation.  To do this, I need to replace our SQL queries with the Hazelcast equivalent.  Hazelcast provides some built-in aggregations, such as a count.  I've been happily using this, but when I came to writing my own aggregations, I had a look at the source code for the CountAggregation.  It can be found here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hazelcast/hazelcast/3.3-RC2/com/hazelcast/mapreduce/aggregation/impl/CountAggregation.java

Aggregations in Hazelcast are implemented using the MapReduce algorithm.  But to me, the source above seems to be really inefficient.  For the Mapper stage of the algorithm, they use a SupplierConsumingMapper, which simply emits mappings using the same key as the supplied key.  What this then means is that the reducing stage doesn't actually reduce anything, because all of the emitted keys are different, and you end up with a whole load of 1's to count up at the final collation stage, rather than a number of partial counts to add together.

Surely what they should be doing is using a mapper which always emits the same key?  Then the combiners and reducers could actually do some combining and reducing.  It seems to me that the source code above is incorrectly using the MapReduce model, although the result you end up with is correct.  Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you're absolutely correct. The implementation is a bit to simple at that place :) Can you please file an issue at github so we won't forget to fix that one. Thanks Chris

Comment: Thanks.  The problem I think will be the same for all aggregations that use a SupplierConsumingMapper (which is I think nearly all built in aggregations), because it simply emits the same key as the key from the IMap.  This means that there will be a Combiner and Reducer for every single IMap entry.  So nothing will be combined and nothing reduced, with all of the collation happening on the calling node in the Collator implementation.